# ssl certificate using ELB in EC2. Redirect http to https

Tags: php, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

I have created an SSL certificate using ELB in EC2. Now I'm trying to redirect http to https using the code below:

```
ServerName xyz.com      
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https      
RewriteRule !/index.php https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]  .
```

The first two times it works, later it is giving errors like this

```
 This page isn’t working 
 www.xyz.com is currently unable to handle this request. 
HTTP ERROR 503
```

I tried so many ways but not working. Finally I'm here to get suggestion from you.

Comment: what else have you tried?

Comment: Try `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `%{SERVER_NAME}`

Comment: Thnq. below code worked for me....ServerName example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !(https|^$)
RewriteRule !/index.php https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]